# how to write a method using hibernate which returns boolean

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

how to create method which returns a boolean through hibernate. I am doing something like this

```
@Override
public Boolean findIfAnswered(long questionId, String principalEmail) {

    Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("realUser.email",principalEmail))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("tourismQuestions.questionId",questionId));
    return .....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with following:

```
select case when (count(scen) > 0)  then true else false end  
from Scenario scen where scen.name = :name
```

Using criteria you can use something like below.

```
public boolean isReleatedToItemType(Integer invoiceId,Integer itemTypeId){
  Criteria criteria=getSession().createCriteria(InvoiceDTO.class);
  addItemCategoryCriteria(criteria,itemTypeId);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleted",0)).add(Restrictions.eq("id",invoiceId));
  return criteria.uniqueResult() != null;
}
```

Refer this for complete solution : http://www.javased.com/?api=org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions

Comment: i have written the above method, but how do i then return the boolean value from it because Criteria has no method which returns boolean  @Alien

Comment: I did your way but it only returns true . Why ? @Alien

Comment: for that debug and check what your query exactly returns if true then here also will return true only.